# write a float buffer to a binary file

Tags: c++, file, ppm

- I have a float buffer with the data of the ppm file. The buffer[0][0] is the 1st element and the buffer[3*width*height][0] is the last element of the data.
- Buffer has elements like this. 1st = 117 2st= 135 3st = 122. It's red, green and blue.
- The point is to write this data into a binary file!

**I try this, getHeight() returns the Height and getWidth() the width of the data.**

```
ofstream output(filename, ios::out | ios::binary);  
output.write((char *)buffer, img.getHeight() * img.getWidth() * 3);
```

**Also i try this, for i=0 to i=3*height*width**

```
fp = fopen(filename, "wb");
fwrite(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer[i][0]), 1, 3*height*width, fp);
```

Comment: How is `buffer` defined?

Comment: @NathanOliver the buffer defined Vec3<float> *buffer; 
i have a function getRawDataPtr that returns the buffer
Vec3<float> * Image::getRawDataPtr() {
 return buffer;
}

Comment: Do you know if `Vec3` is naturally serializeable?

Comment: @NathanOliver i have a header file Vec3.h that represents a triplet of values of the same type S. The Vec3 class is used as a generic three-dimensional vector and thus it defines several  numerical operators that can be used on Vec3<S> and S data.

Answer (score 0):

A float is 4 bytes each.
fwrite() doesn't know of the type you're writing, so for the size, you need to also multiply by the size of each element.

```
fwrite(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buffer[i][0]), 1, 3*height*width * sizeof(float), fp);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
     ofstream out("blah.txt");
     float val = 10.0f;

     out << fixed << setprecision(5) << val << endl;
     out.close();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you also add some explanation?